# python unicode: How can I judge if a string needs to be decoded into utf-8?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I have a function accepting requests from the network. Most of the time, the string passed in is not unicode, but sometimes it is.

I have code to convert everything to unicode, but it reports this error:

```
message.create(username, unicode(body, "utf-8"), self.get_room_name(),\
TypeError: decoding Unicode is not supported
```

I think the reason is the 'body' parameter is already unicode, so `unicode()` raises an exception.

Is there any way to avoid this exception, e.g. judge the type before the conversion?

Comment: Note: unicode and UTF-8 are not the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You do not decode to UTF-8, you *encode to* UTF-8 or *decode from*.
2. You can safely decode from UTF8 even if it's just ASCII. ASCII is a subset of UTF8.
3. The easiest way to detect if it needs decoding or not is

   ```
   if not isinstance(data, unicode):
       # It's not Unicode!
       data = data.decode('UTF8')
   ```

Comment: Small correction: the type to check for is `unicode`, not `Unicode`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use either this:

```
try:
   body = unicode(body)
except UnicodeDecodeError:
   body = body.decode('utf8')
```

Or this:

```
try:
   body = unicode(body, 'utf8')
except TypeError:
   body = unicode(body)
```

Answer (score -1):

Mark Pilgrim wrote a Python library to guess text encodings:

- http://chardet.feedparser.org/

On Unicode and UTF-8, the first two sections of chapter 4 of his book ‘Dive into Python 3’ are pretty great:

- http://diveintopython3.org/strings.html

Answer (score -1):

This is what I use:

```
def to_unicode_or_bust(obj, encoding='utf-8'):
    if isinstance(obj, basestring):
        if not isinstance(obj, unicode):
            obj = unicode(obj, encoding)
    return obj
```

It's taken from this presentation: http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/

And this is a sample code that uses it:

```
def hash_it_safe(s):
    try:
        s = to_unicode_or_bust(s)
        return hash_it_basic(s)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return hash_it_basic(s)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        assert type(s) is unicode
        return hash_it_basic(s.encode('utf-8'))
```

Anyone have some thoughts on how to improve this code? ;)