# How to determine if a string is escaped unicode

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x

How do you determine if a string contains escaped unicode so you know whether or not to run `.decode("unicode-escape")`?

For example:

**test.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
str_escaped = '"A\u0026B"'
str_unicode = '"Война́ и миръ"'

arr_all_strings = [str_escaped, str_unicode]

def is_escaped_unicode(str):
    #how do I determine if this is escaped unicode?
    pass

for str in arr_all_strings:
    if is_escaped_unicode(str):
        str = str.decode("unicode-escape")
    print str
```

**Current output:**

```
"A\u0026B"
"Война́ и миръ"
```

**Expected output:**

```
"A&B"
"Война́ и миръ"
```

How do I define `is_escaped_unicode(str)` to determine if the string that's passed is actually escaped unicode?

Comment: Is this similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461183/python-unicode-how-can-i-judge-if-a-string-needs-to-be-decoded-into-utf-8

Comment: @Fallenreaper not really. The type of `str_escaped` and `str_unicode` are both `str`. Neither is of type `unicode`. Put another way, `isinstance(str, unicode)` is `False` for both strings.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to add the `python-2.x` tag, because the given output isn't reproducible with python 3.

Comment: Unicode escapes and non-ascii characters aren't mutually exclusive. What what the expected output be with an input of `"\u0026ойн"`? That clearly contains a unicode escape, but if you call `"\u0026ойн".decode("unicode-escape")` you get `&Ð¾Ð¹Ð½`

Comment: @BenMcCormack it is a similar concept though.  You can tweak it, but follow a similar course of action

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
str_escaped = u'"A\u0026B"'
str_unicode = '"Война́ и миръ"'

arr_all_strings = [str_escaped, str_unicode]

def is_ascii(s):
    return all(ord(c) < 128 for c in s)

def is_escaped_unicode(str):
    #how do I determine if this is escaped unicode?
    if is_ascii(str): # escaped unicode is ascii
        return True
    return False

for str in arr_all_strings:
    if is_escaped_unicode(str):
        str = str.decode("unicode-escape")
    print str
```

The following code will work for your case.

Explain:

- All string in str_escaped is in Ascii range.
- Char in str_unicode do not contain in Ascii range.

Comment: You changed the type of one of the variables...  I think it's safe to assume they are incoming data, not actually source code literals like in the example.

Comment: @wim I don't think it matters; the code still works if you change the unicode variable back to a string.

Comment: This is clever. I hadn't thought about escaped unicode being ASCII. At any rate, the only time I want to call `.decode("unicode-escape")` is if I'm dealing with ASCII text. If for some reason I get something crazy like `Война́ \u0026 миръ`, the `\u0026` will be left in place, which will be good enough.

Comment: This is unsafe and can crash if the data was not encoded with a unicode-escape in the first place.  For example, `is_escaped_unicode('\\')` returns True.  But no input data could encode to `'\\'`, and the program will crash when you try to decode it.

Answer (score 7):

You can not.

There is no way to tell if '"A\u0026B"' originally came from some text that was encoded, or if the data are just the bytes '"A\u0026B"', or if we arrived there from some *other* encoding.

> How do ... you know whether or not to run `.decode("unicode-escape")`

You have to know if someone earlier has called `text.encode('unicode-escape')`.  The bytes themselves can not tell you.

You can certainly *guess*, by looking for \u or \U escape sequences, or by just try/except the decoding and see what happens, but I don't recommend to go down this route.

If you encounter a bytestring in your application, and you don't already *know* what the encoding is, then your problem lies elsewhere and should be fixed elsewhere.

Comment: "then your problem lies elsewhere and should be fixed elsewhere." I agree with this line of thinking and I'll see if we can figure out why there's a disparity in the underlying data and if we can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a crude way to do it. Try decoding as unicode-escape, and if that succeeds the resulting string will be shorter than the original string.

```
str_escaped = '"A\u0026B"'
str_unicode = '"Война́ и миръ"'
arr_all_strings = [str_escaped, str_unicode]

def decoder(s):
    y = s.decode('unicode-escape')
    return y if len(y) < len(s) else s.decode('utf8')

for s in arr_all_strings:
    print s, decoder(s)
```

**output**

```
"A\u0026B" "A&B"
"Война и миръ" "Война и миръ"
```

---

But seriously, you'll save yourself a lot of pain if you can migrate to Python 3. And if you can't immediately migrate to Python 3, you may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: answer is ingenious, but please don't overlook his recommendation to adopt Python 3 if these issues are important to you. It cleanly separates the world of encoded data (which is transmitted and stored as `bytes` or `bytearrays`) and pure text (held as `str` objects).

Comment: does this work in Python 2.7? I'm getting an error when trying to run the code: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-6: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: I modified the return line of `decoder` to be `return y if len(y) < len(s) else s` and that ended up working

Comment: @BenMcCormack It _should_ work, but I tested it in Python 2.6.6 (I normally use Python 3.6.0 these days, and I don't have 2.7). Is your script encoded with UTF-8, and does it have a valid UTF-8 encoding directive, like the `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` one in the code in your question?

Comment: @BenMcCormack BTW, do you just want to use this to decode literal strings, i.e. strings literally written in your script, or do you want to use it on data that your script reads from a file or some other external source?

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, I have the encoding directive at the top of the file. I'm using this to process input from a shell command that outputs tab-delimited text.

Comment: Per @wim's point, this does seem to be more of an upstream problem. I'm going to raise it upstream as well, but I need for it to work if I can't get the source data changed.

Comment: @BenMcCormack I agree that it would be best to get this fixed upstream, since a program that can output both  `"A\u0026B"` and `"Война́ и миръ"` in the one stream is probably doing something wrong. BTW, the `# -*- coding:` directive only affects how the interpreter decodes the script itself (and thus any non-ASCII literal strings it contains), it has no bearing on how a script processes external data.

Comment: @BenMcCormack The reason I wrote `return y if len(y) < len(s) else s.decode('utf8')` is so that the return value of `decoder` is consistent. I assumed that the input strings are byte strings, encoded with UTF-8, like the strings in your example, not Unicode strings; in Python 2, Unicode literals are prefixed with `u`. The `s.decode('unicode-escape')` and `s.decode('utf8')` calls each return a Unicode string (a sequence of Unicode codepoints).

Comment: This is unsafe and can crash if the data was not encoded with a unicode-escape in the first place.  For example, using the input string `'abc\\'` will raise `UnicodeDecodeError` and you don't handle that.